# Oracle PRAGMA SERIALLY_REUSABLE;

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've a package defined like this

```
create or replace 
package my_pk as
  myVar number := 0;
  procedure try;
end;

create or replace 
package body my_pk as
  procedure try as
  begin
    myVar := myVar + 1;
    dbms_output.put_line(myVar);
  end;
end;
```

and i've created a simple script to call it

```
begin
my_pk.try;
end;
```

If i execute it serveral times, myVar have the value: 1, 2, 3, and so on.

For example, i need to use that variable as global variable, but i dont want that maintain the state accross different session.

Looking on the net i've see the command  **PRAGMA SERIALLY_REUSABLE** , this is the correct way to define global variables that have their own instance, accross multiple session ?

Comment: Package variables are in the PGA, so they are *always* private to a session. And you have declared it in the package (and not within a procedure or function) so it's *already* global. Not only that, you have it in the package spec, which means it is public to all other objects in the schema. If you want it to be available across multiple sessions, you would either store it in a table or in a context (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/app_context.htm#DBSEG70071).

Answer (score 2):

So currently if you call your package multiple times within the same session the value of the variable will be persistent and you will be able to iterate it (as you found).

However, you will notice that even without `serially_reusable`, the value of the variable is not persistent between multiple sessions. To demonstrate this open up another instance of SQL*Plus or a new window in PL/SQL Developer / Toad (each is a unique Oracle session). Each session create a new instance of my_pk the first time you call it.

`Pragma serially_reusable` could be used if you want the package to be re-initialized each time a call to it is made, even within the same session.

If you want the value of the package variable to be constant, you should use the `constant` keyword i.e.

```
myVar constant number := 0;
```

However, you will not be able to change its value, even within the package.

Which way you set this up really depends on your specific requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would like to have some variables that could be used by all my procedure/functions. For this reason i have delcared the outside any procedure/function, because i dont want create a procedure and pass that variable accross the other procedure/functions. But, if i declare that variable outise, their value is maintained in the same session. I want it to be re-initialized...

Comment: PRAGMA SERIALLY_REUSABLE;
This command should be declared in both Package and package Body. When ever there is a call to the package the global variable is initialized. Thus, if the package Global variable is stateless i.e. it can be reinitialized. Its better to use the above command. Thanks it really helped my implementation.